# почему в методе Compare object со знаком вопроса?

Tags: c#

```
public Int32 CompareTo(object? value)
```

Что означает вопрос?

Answer (score 3):

В C# 8 ввели, а в C# 9 закрепили [Nullable Reference Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types), которые нужны по сути для статического анализа кода. На концептуальном уровне, значение null для некоторых классов просто не имеет смысла в некотором контексте и хотелось бы этот момент выявить на этапе компиляции.